# How to pass props through AppRouter

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I need to get `userRole` via AppRouter:

**App.js**

```
  <BrowserRouter>    
       <AppRouter
           userRole = {userRole}
        />
  </BrowserRouter>
```

**AppRouter.js**

```
const AppRouter = observer((userRole) => {
    const {user} = useContext(Context) 
     <Routes>                                                                   
                {user.isAuth && authRoutes.map(({path, Component}) =>                  
                    <Route
                        key={path}
                        path={path}
                        element={
                            <Component
                                userRole={userRole}  //here i pass
                            />
                        }
                        exact
                    />            
                )}
                <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to={JADE_ROUTE} />}/>               
            </Routes>
```

Here my `Component` but `userRole` is already **undefined**

```
const CarPage = observer(({userRole}) => {
   console.log(userRole)
   return <h1>{userRole}<h1/>
}
```

Comment: in AppRouter userRole has the right option

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppRouter` component it seems you're not extracting the `userRole` from `props`. Could that be it?

```
const AppRouter = observer((userRole) => {
```

should be

```
const AppRouter = observer(({userRole}) => {
```